# Indexing on column field is not working with ElasticSearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-model

I'm implementing ElasticSearch integration in my model :

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
class MissionDef < ActiveRecord::Base
  # field: name (String(40))
  # field: icon (String(2000))
  # field: definition (String)
  # field: public, boolean

  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    self.as_json(
     only: [:id, :name]
     )
  end
end
```

and In my Rails Console I did:

```
MissionDef.import

MissionDef.first

MissionDef id: 226, ade_channel_key: "d403d658313e6c35ce", name: "Test Mission", icon: "/app/assets/images/badges/Showedup.png", definition: "{}", deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2015-08-04 11:30:08", updated_at: "2015-08-04 11:30:08", container_id: 883, public: true
```

My Query

1) when I'm doing search with other field  value other than name and id which is not indexed it gives me the search result.
for eg:

result = MissionDef.search 'app' --- it works
result.records.count => 1

which should not be the case I guess.

2) Missiondef.first.as_indexed_json  =>  does not work properly it gives me o/p  as whole object as JSON

{"id"=>226, "ade_channel_key"=>"d403d658313e6c35ce", "name"=>"Test Mission", "icon"=>"/app/assets/images/badges/Showedup.png", "definition"=>"{}", "created_at"=>Tue, 04 Aug 2015 11:30:08 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Tue, 04 Aug 2015 11:30:08 UTC +00:00, "container_id"=>883, "public"=>true}

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the `elasticsearch-rails` gem before, but by default I know that elasticsearch will search entire documents, so if you only want to specify specific fields in your query.  So in your given example, the `app` is matching the icon field: /**app**/assets/images/badges/Showedup.png

Try specifying the fields you want to search - read more in their documentation here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/master/elasticsearch-model/README.md#the-elasticsearch-dsl

So in this case it may be something like:

```
result = MissionDef.search query: {match:  {name: "app" }}
result.records.count #=> should be 0 this time
```

Comment: Thank you, but my 2) query too not working Missiondef.first.as_indexed_json  instead of giving id and name in json format it gives whole object in json format

Comment: Sorry Mangala, I'm not sure what the answer to (2) might be, it does look odd though.  I've not used `elasticsearch-rails` before so I'm not sure how the `as_indexed_json` method is supposed to be used.

However, [from the example in the documentation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model#model-serialization), the one difference I can see is that it doesn't include the `Callbacks` module, which may be part of it perhaps?

Comment: Thanks I have got my query solved for both the questions. Thanks